# Can server side PHP send encrypted data to client side?

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, client-server, webclient

I need to send images from server side to client side.

If I just echo the image data, it's not safe. In the client side, I need to process and use the images (I will use these images with web unity) but I don't want the original images to be exposed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will SSL do what you need?

If you need more (to prevent snooping), check out the http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php library: you'll need to find a corresponding decryption function in Unity. Encypt the raw image data (e.g. jpeg or png) and send over the wire; decrypt in Unity and rebuild the image.

Comment: If unity requests the image, then just use HTTPS and the SSL is automatic.